# When to use Eq in Haskell type declarations?

Tags: haskell

It is my understanding that you should add `Eq ...` to a functions' type declaration when you use `==` or `\=` to compare one of the functions parameters. However, GHCi says that the following also requires an `Eq` type class:

```
take' _ [] = []
take' 0 _ = []
take' n (x:xs) = x : take' (n - 1) xs

%% Needs the following type class
%% take' :: (Eq t, Num t) => t -> [a] -> [a]
```

Why does it require `Eq t` to be added to the type declaration, even though the `n` parameter is never compared with anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern match `take' 0 _ = ...` is *syntactic sugar* for an equality check, namely

```
take' _ [] = []
take' n _
    | n==0  = []
take' n (x:xs) = x : take' (n - 1) xs
```

So this requires `Eq t` if you want the counter-argument to be polymorphic `t`. Also `Num t` so you can have the value `0` and to calculate `n-1`.

Practically speaking, there's not much compelling reason to use `take` with any type but `Int`, so the standard version just isn't polymorphic *at all* in that argument:

```
take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
```

with `Int` being known as an instance of both `Eq` and `Num`.

Comment: That make sense, thank you. Wouldn't `take` still be polymorphic with type `take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`, because the lists can be of any type?

Comment: Yeah, but not polymorphic in the number type.

Comment: Could I also ask why `Num t` is neccesary, instead of say `Intergral t`? Because the function wouldn't work if you were to pass a float / double into it anyway. Is it simply because Haskell isn't able to recognize that it wouldn't work with a float / double?

Comment: Well, it _would_ work with `Float`, just it would behave stupid for non-integral ones – but the compiler doesn't know what's stupid. What if you _wanted_ the function to just keep on going if the argument is fractional and flips over to negative in the recursion? You're right, this doesn't make sense and if you make it number-polymorphic you _should_ require `Integral`. But as I said, even better you should just use a concrete number type like `Int` (or, to be completely type-sound, [`Natural`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Natural.html#t:Natural)).